# Ubuntu 16.04 ignores .jpg (lower case) and shows .JPG (upper case) image!

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04, using caja, when I try to look at xyz.jpg and there is a xyz.JPG in the directory, I see xyz.JPG, the xyz.jpg is ignored.
Apache2 does the same thing. so does firefox open a file.
Makes me think its something to do with the file system?
We have two 16.04s both do it, one an upgrade, one a fresh install.
The reason I do this is I take pics and rescale them (fewer pixels) in the same directory for web pages.
Paul Turner

Comment: Probably because the extension .jpg and .JPG are the same file type. I wonder if the same holds true for xyz, XYZ, Xyz, XYz, XyZ, xYZ, xYz and xyZ?

Comment: AFAIK the Ubuntu filesystem is case sensitive, so image.jpg and image.JPG technically aren't the same name. It's possible that certain applications, like Apache and Caja, aren't case-sensitive, and have to figure out a way which to view (or don't have any handling and prioritizing capital letters is just a coincidental result). You should probably use different names.